# Gradle batch test log events

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle

I have a Java project (on GitHub) with over 4600 unit tests that run in about 13 minutes on Travis CI.

By default, the webpage of Travis [shows all unit test methods](https://travis-ci.org/ReactiveX/RxJava/builds/156896225#L195) with `> STARTED` but the whole log gets trimmed due to the sheer number of the output. If I turn off these logs in Gradle, the build fails due to lack of standard output for 10 minutes.

Is there a way to setup Gradle (2.14) to log on a per test-class level instead of test-method level? I've tried maxGranularity = 1 and 2 but that just doesn't show anything.